# Cathay Pacific overnight layover

Tags: air-travel, us-citizens, layovers, hong-kong, cathay-pacific

I will be traveling from Bali to Hong Kong (Cathay Pacific) then have an overnight layover (17 hours) before my flight back to LAX (American). I am traveling on a U.S. passport. Is it possible to get my bags at Hong Kong to stay in a hotel, and then recheck them back for LAX?

Do I need to just tell the person at the ticket counter in Bali?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most airlines will allow you to get your bags during a long layover, but to be sure you should call the airline directly and ask including all your specific flight information (flight times, fare class, status, etc.)

However, if possible, I'd use carry-on for the layover. You'll be out of the airport a lot faster, you can come back to the airport later (since you don't need to re-check bags) and you don't need to schlepp your bigger bags around. Most carry on will easily accommodate a day/night pack.

Comment: +1 Regardless of whether a layover is planned, I travel with what I would need for an overnight at a hotel, including a basic change of clothing, in my carry-on. Flights can be delayed or diverted and checked bags can be temporarily lost.